# How to turn off automatic response keyboard bounce and disappear automatic scrolling in IOS WKwebView

Tags: ios, keyboard, wkwebview

When I was developing the IOS app, there was a page that was all WKwebView, but there was a fix element at the top. When using the keyboard function, it would move the entire page up, which had a poor user experience. How can I solve this problem? My current solution is to manually monitor the keyboard to change the size of the WKwebView, but the WKwebView itself will still move automatically, resulting in jumping animations, which is also not good, Is there a better solution? thanks

```
#pragma mark - UIScrollViewDelegate
- (void)scrollViewDidScroll:(UIScrollView *)scrollView
{
    CGPoint newOffSet = scrollView.contentOffset;
    if (newOffSet.y > 0)
    {
        if (self.isChangeKeyBoard)
        {

            [scrollView setContentOffset:CGPointZero];
        }
        else
        {
            return;
        }
    }
}

- (void)registerKeyboardNotifications
{
    
    [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self
                                         selector:@selector(keyboardWillShow:)
                                             name:UIKeyboardWillShowNotification object:nil];
    [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self
                                             selector:@selector(keyboardDidShow:)
                                             name:UIKeyboardDidShowNotification object:nil];
    [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self
                                         selector:@selector(keyboardWillHide:)
                                             name:UIKeyboardWillHideNotification object:nil];
    [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self
                                         selector:@selector(keyboardDidHiden)
                                             name:UIKeyboardDidHideNotification object:nil];
}
- (void)keyboardWillShow:(NSNotification *)notification
{
    self.isChangeKeyBoard = YES;
    CGSize kbSize = [[[notification userInfo] objectForKey:UIKeyboardFrameEndUserInfoKey] CGRectValue].size;
    [self.webView mas_updateConstraints:^(MASConstraintMaker *make) {
        make.edges.equalTo(self.view).insets(UIEdgeInsetsMake(0, 0, kbSize.height, 0));
    }];
}

- (void)keyboardDidShow:(NSNotification *)notification
{
    self.isChangeKeyBoard = NO;
    CGSize kbSize = [[[notification userInfo] objectForKey:UIKeyboardFrameEndUserInfoKey] CGRectValue].size;
//    [self.webView mas_updateConstraints:^(MASConstraintMaker *make) {
//        make.edges.equalTo(self.view).insets(UIEdgeInsetsMake(0, 0, kbSize.height, 0));
//    }];
    UIEdgeInsets oldInset = self.webView.scrollView.contentInset;
    self.webView.scrollView.contentInset = UIEdgeInsetsMake(0, 0, -kbSize.height, 0);
}

- (void)keyboardWillHide:(NSNotification *)notification
{
    self.isChangeKeyBoard = YES;
//    self.webView.scrollView.contentOffset = CGPointZero;
//    self.webView.scrollView.contentInset = UIEdgeInsetsMake(0, 0, 0, 0);
    CGSize kbSize = [[[notification userInfo] objectForKey:UIKeyboardFrameEndUserInfoKey] CGRectValue].size;
    BYLog(@"%@", NSStringFromUIEdgeInsets(self.webView.scrollView.contentInset))
    BYLog(@"%@", NSStringFromCGPoint(self.webView.scrollView.contentOffset))
    //self.webView.scrollView.contentInset = UIEdgeInsetsMake(0, 0, 0, 0);
    if (self.tabBarController.tabBar.hidden)
    {
        CGFloat bottom = kSafeAreaBottomHeight;
        [self.webView  mas_updateConstraints:^(MASConstraintMaker *make) {
            make.edges.equalTo(self.view).insets(UIEdgeInsetsMake(0, 0, bottom, 0));
        }];
    }
    else
    {
        CGFloat bottom = kTabBarHeight;
        [self.webView mas_updateConstraints:^(MASConstraintMaker *make) {
            make.edges.equalTo(self.view).insets(UIEdgeInsetsMake(0, 0, bottom, 0));
        }];
    }

}
- (void)keyboardDidHiden
{
    _isChangeKeyBoard = NO;
   // self.webView.scrollView.contentInset = UIEdgeInsetsMake(0, 0, 0, 0);
}
```